# Updating record not working in LINQ to SQL with primary key set in class

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have code which should update ma database:

```
public static void UPDATEroz(DataClasses1DataContext dc, string nazwavar)
{
    var update = (from p in dc.dataTable
                  where p.nazwa.Contains(nazwavar)
                  select p).First();

    Debug.WriteLine(update.nazwa);
    update.roz = update.roz++;
    Debug.WriteLine("Updating");

    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But after running this method nothing changes in database. Inserting new records works fine.

I checked every possible solution in the web and nothing worked for me.

In data class primary key is marked for the table:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
```

I also tried to remove PK from my table without changing dataclass but that didn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. I don't know why but
 `update.roz = update.roz++;`
Was not incrementing the value and simply chaniging it to
 `update.roz = update.roz + 1;`
worked for me.

Comment: `a = a++;` will not increment a. as assignment is done first. U can use `a=a+1;` or `a = ++a;`